# Errors starting with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new with `JavaScript and Developement on Android`. I installed `Eclipse` but I can't even run the "Hello World" program, included when you created a new project !

Please help me, I spent the two last days installing this IDE (even tried `Android Studio`),
but there is always the same error :

> Could not find Chwet.apk!
>
> And there seems to be an error with the "R", like in
>   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Here is my code :

```
package com.example.chwet;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to clean your project go to Project menu in eclipse and clean your project and let me know whether the error is gone or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error]

Comment: Did you mean "I am new to Java and Eclipse"? Can you start simple Java applications (non-Android) from within eclipse? Do you have the JDK installed or just the JRE? What does the Eclipse error log say?

Comment: I am new to both Java and Eclipse. The error log says : "R cannot be resolve as a variable"

Comment: Cleaning the project doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at following tutorial to get start with Android application development.

[Hello world example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-hello-world-example/).

Comment: You are welcome. Book mark that web site. It will be useful for you to understand Android basic concepts. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to add missing packages. It will automatically remove your errors.

Comment: Didn't work, I am apparently up-to-date... But tanks ;)

Comment: Ok.. But keep that command in your mind. It will be useful in your application development

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing android R class , import R class with your package name.